# Adding cache worker role causes build error

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-caching

I have an Azure cloud service project to which I am adding a cache worker role. While local build goes through fine, I get the following error on my server builds :

```
CloudServices38 : The entrypoint dll is not defined for worker role <cachename>
```

What is wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the Azure DLLs are marked **Copy Local = True** in the properties window.  Also, package your projects, then unzip them.  Once you build the package, you will have a file YourProject.cspkg.  Change the extension from .cspkg to .zip and extract the files.  In these files you should see a file with the extension .cssx YourProject_.cssx.  Change the extension from .cssx to .zip and extract again.  You project that is deployed will be in the folder YourProject\sitesroot\0 - verufy all the files you are expecting (i.e. content and everything that is in the bin directory on your local build.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a `Build` and a `Publish` separately. I ran into the same problem on my project and this fixed it.

1) Visual Studio Build (or MSBuild) action with arguments `/t:Build` (clean here)

2) Visual Studio Build (or MSBuild) action with arguments `/t:Publish` (do not clean here)

**Note:** I had to run these actions separately (not `/Build;Publish`) otherwise I got an error about the cloud service entry point.

Pieced this together from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343602/tf-build-definition-with-publish-target-and-running-unit-tests) and from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c69b4343-1c6b-4ac4-a9d6-cd35287e6783/tfs-not-building-unit-test-project-during-ci-builds-skipping-tests?forum=TFService) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/4e6a83b7-7e7e-4a12-979a-6338c9b27aae/command-line-publish-error-with-azure-14-august-update?forum=windowsazuredevelopment).